# Understanding scopes in Ruby

Tags: ruby, recursion, scope

I am trying to deal with a very weird (at least to me) situation in Ruby. My code is the following:

```
class ScopeTest
  attr_accessor :flag

  def flagtest
    puts "SELF: " + self.flag.to_s
    puts "INST: " + flag.to_s
    if flag == 1
      flag = 0
      puts "SELF: " + self.flag.to_s
      puts "INST: " + flag.to_s
      self.flag = 0
      puts "SELF: " + self.flag.to_s
      puts "INST: " + flag.to_s
      flagtest
    else
      puts "SELF: " + self.flag.to_s
      puts "INST: " + flag.to_s
    end
  end
end

st = ScopeTest.new
st.flag = 1
st.flagtest
```

And the output is the following:

```
SELF: 1
INST: 1
SELF: 1
INST: 0
SELF: 0
INST: 0
SELF: 0
INST: 0
SELF: 0
INST:
```

What's weird is that the `flag` variable is `nil` the last time I print it (inside the `else`) but `0` straight before that (before the `if...else` in the flagtest method)?

When I remove a few lines of code, everything seems back to normal as the following code:

```
class ScopeTest
  attr_accessor :flag

  def flagtest
    puts "SELF: " + self.flag.to_s
    puts "INST: " + flag.to_s
    if flag == 1
      self.flag = 0
      puts "SELF: " + self.flag.to_s
      puts "INST: " + flag.to_s
      flagtest
    else
      puts "SELF: " + self.flag.to_s
      puts "INST: " + flag.to_s
    end
  end
end

st = ScopeTest.new
st.flag = 1
st.flagtest
```

gives the following output:

```
SELF: 1
INST: 1
SELF: 0
INST: 0
SELF: 0
INST: 0
SELF: 0
INST: 0
```

Any clues as to what and why is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`flag = 0` creates a local variable called flag whose scope goes to the end of the method. Any use of `flag` that appears lexically after that assignment refers to the local variable. Any previous appearance (as well as any appearance of `self.flag`) refers to the getter method.

So the `flag` in the `else` refers to the local variable. Since the local variable never got a value in the `else`-branch, its value is `nil`.

Comment: Right, lexically after.

Comment: But the `flag` before the `if...else` block is not nil because it got the value I set to `st.flag` (outside the method)? (That, in practice, means that there is actually two variables called `flag`: the one before the local assignment and the one after it, no?)

Comment: @sebkomianos This answer and #SergioTulentsev answer explained the reason very properly... Both are correct! And you can check the test from the output of my answer...

Comment: @sebkomianos Yes, there are two variables. The local variable created by `flag = 0` and the instance variable `@flag`. The latter is never directly used in your code (i.e. no `@` appears in your code), but is returned by the `flag` method and set by the `flag=` method. The `flag` before the `if` refers to the `flag` method and thus returns the value of the `@flag` instance variable.

Answer (score 3):

It's because you have assignment to a local variable, `flag = 0`. IIRC, local variables are created at parse time and are scoped to the method. They are initialized with `nil` by default. So, in your `then` clause you assign it a value, before it is accessed. But when you re-enter the method, you go to `else` clause and `flag` is left uninitialized (that is, `nil`).

```
class ScopeTest
  attr_accessor :flag

  def flagtest
    # if you comment this line, the method will output 1, 1
    # if you don't comment, it will output 1, nil, because the assignment to local variable was never done.
    #   but local var itself was created.
    flag = 3 if false

    puts self.flag.inspect
    puts flag.inspect
  end
end

st = ScopeTest.new
st.flag = 1
st.flagtest
# >> 1
# >> nil
```

Answer (score 2):

See the reason :-

```
class ScopeTest
  attr_accessor :flag

  def flagtest
    p defined?(flag)
    if flag == 1
      p defined?(flag)
      flag = 0
      p defined?(flag)
      self.flag = 0
      flagtest
    else
      p defined?(flag)
    end
  end
end

st = ScopeTest.new
st.flag = 1
```

***output***

```
"method"
"method"
"local-variable"
"method"
"local-variable"
```

Comment: What about the `else` condition?

Comment: @AndrewMarshall I am done.. the method `defined?` does the all answer clearly.. :)